# Highcharts legend spread out to full width

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is it possible to spread legend items out over the full width of the chart, while maintaining wrapping? I'm looking for something like the flex alignment property `space-between`.

What I have:

[image]

What I want (except for only having 3 items on the first row, which is fine):
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your configuration and styles on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I do not think there is an option for that. To have such layout I think you need to manually reposition the legend or build your own legend with html/css. Example https://codepen.io/kevintcoughlin/pen/WrKLMe

Comment: @arcquim here is a fiddle with a close config: https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/7540/

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically reposition legend items on load/redraw events.

Based on your fiddle, the method can be like this (for html items width must be grabbed differently)

```
function adjustLegend() {
  const legend = this.legend
  const legendWidth = this.chartWidth - 20

  legend.allItems.forEach((item, i, allItems) => {
    const {width, height} = item.legendGroup.getBBox()
    const itemsPerRow = i < 3 ? 3 : 2

    item.legendGroup.attr({
      translateX: (i % itemsPerRow) * (legendWidth - width) / (itemsPerRow - 1),
      translateY: Math.floor(i / 3) * (height + 5)
    })
  })
}
```

In chart options:

```
events: {
  load: adjustLegend,
  redraw: adjustLegend
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/f6btakom/1/